# Unable to define custom redis hash with annotation @RedisHash

Tags: spring-boot, redis

Trying to make Redis Entries Environment specific like dev, qa and uat. So that one common Redis Cache environment can be used across various environments.

Current cache key entries are like: **empCache**:101_Abcd

Want keys to be like below: **empCache:dev**:101_Abcd, **empCache:uat**:101_Abcd

> Requirement:
>
> 1. CRUD operations.
> 2. If Dev cache is cleared/updated it should not impact entries of other environments like qa and uat.

Current Code

```
EmpBean 
@RedisHash("empCache")
//Want to set RedisHash key as "empCache" + Spring Profile (like dev,qa,uat)
public class EmpBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    String empCacheKey;
    
    /*EmpId*/
    private int empId;
    
    /*EmpName*/
    private String empName;
    
}


Repository
---------------------------
@Repository
public interface EmpRepo extends CrudRepository<EmpBean, String> {}
```

If I try to add a reference to read spring boot profile from application properties, I get below compilation error.

```
The value for annotation attribute RedisHash.value must be a constant expression
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally used jedis to achieve the same -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Code sample is below.

```
try (Jedis jedisRef = new Jedis(env.getProperty("spring.redis.host"))) {
            String empKey = "empCache" + "::" + dev + "::" + "customKeyName";
            jedisRef.setex(empKey, expiry,
                    stringToSave);
}
```